# When hot reload on vite, want run prettier and lint automatically

Tags: eslint, vite, prettier

I'm tryin to setting up configuration to run automatically [npm run format] (prettier) and [npm run lint] (eslint) on vite hot reload.

I googled about this, but theres no any solutions what I wanna do.
Maybe vscode tasks.json will can that, But I don't know how to setting up it is.
I already create .eslintrc.cjs and .prettierrc files and these files can run with [npm] command.

What should I do to run prettier and eslint automatically when vite hot reload?

Or, every programmer do [npm run lint / prettier]?

This is structure.

https://imgur.com/a/TSzoMzX